# Conditional countif date is before today and cell in another column is blank

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

Column AE has dates
Column AG has text

I need to count how many rows have these occurrences:

1. Column AE is before today
   AND
2. Column AG is blank

I've been trying for a while, looking around the questions and answers, I got this, but it gives me an error:

```
=COUNTIF(AE3:AE124,"<"&TODAY()), isblank(AG3:AG124)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have multiple IFs, use `COUNTIFS` instead of `COUNTIF`.

```
 =countifs(AE3:AE124, "<"&today(), AG3:AG124, "=")
```

The format is: first range, criterion for it, second range, criterion for it, and so on.

The condition `"="` means being empty, while `"<>"` would be "non-empty".